# Selecting menu item using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, html-select

I have simple `PhantomJS` script to parse `Javascript` content of website to `html`. (Some data is then extracted from the `html` code using other tool.)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');// File System Module
var output = '/tmp/sourcefile'; // path for saving the local file
page.open('targeturl', function() { // open the file
  fs.write(output,page.content,'w'); // Write the page to the local file using page.content
  phantom.exit(); // exit PhantomJs
});
```

(I got these lines of code from http://kochi-coders.com/2014/05/06/scraping-a-javascript-enabled-web-page-using-beautiful-soup-and-phantomjs/)

This used to work when all targets had direct links. Now they are behind the same url and there is drop down menu:

```
<select id="observation-station-menu" name="station" onchange="updateObservationProductsBasedOnForm(this);">
  <option value="101533">Alajärvi Möksy</option>
  ...    
  <option value="101541">Äänekoski Kalaniemi</option>
  </select>
```

This is the menu item I would actually like to load:

```
<option value="101632">Joensuu Linnunlahti</option>
```

Because of this menu my script only downloads data related to the default location. How I load contents of other item from the menu and download `html` content of that item instead?

My target site is this: http://ilmatieteenlaitos.fi/suomen-havainnot

(If there is better way than `PhantomJS` for doing this I could use it just as well. My interest is in dealing with the data once get it scraped and I chose `PhantomJS` just because it was the first thing that worked. Some options might be limited because my server is a `Raspberry Pi` and might not work on it: [Python Selenium: Firefox profile error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208288/python-selenium-firefox-profile-error/34209387#34209387))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly call the function, which is defined in the underlying js on that page:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');// File System Module
var output = '/tmp/sourcefile'; // path for saving the local file
page.open('targeturl', function() { // open the file
  page.evaluate(function() {
     updateObservationProducts(101632, 'weather');
  });
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    fs.write(output,page.content,'w'); // Write the page to the local file using page.content
    phantom.exit(); // exit PhantomJs
  }, 1000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 

});
```

For the waiting to render, see this [phantomjs not waiting for "full" page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340038/phantomjs-not-waiting-for-full-page-load) , I copy pasted a part from rhunwicks solution.

Comment: This acted similarly to the other answer. The passed without errors but contained data of the default selection.

Answer (score 3):

Since the page have jQuery, you can do:

```
page.open('targeturl', function() { // open the file
  page.evaluate(function() {
    jQuery('#observation-station-menu').val('101632').change();
  });  //change the checkbox, then fires the event
  fs.write(output,page.content,'w'); // Write the page to the local file using page.content
  phantom.exit(); // exit PhantomJs
});
```

Comment: Your variant is probably better, since it will be easier to update I guess.

Comment: I ran this but the resulting file still contained information of the default choice. From the file: `<option value="100971" selected="selected">Helsinki Kaisaniemi</option>
`

Comment: @MadocComadrin Well, duh, there is a delay between changing the value and seeing a new image. You need to add a delay to your script.